# Disable interaction for views behind background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch, user-interaction

To show a help view I've put an UIImageView which behind has some UIButtons. How can I disable user interaction of these buttons? If I touch this image where buttons are behind, they responds to touch events.

CODE FOR IMAGE BACKGROUND:

```
self.helpBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
self.helpBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.75];
self.helpBackground.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.helpBackground];
```

I've used   self.helpBackground.userInteractionEnabled = NO; but didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to disable userInteraction for all the buttons not helpBackground imageview..!

Comment: You can put all buttons as an button.hidden=YES when helpBackground will open.

Answer (score 0):

Put your buttons in a array and loop through them and disable them:

```
NSArray *buttonsArray = @[yourButton1, yourButton2];

for (UIButton *button in buttonsArray) {
button.enabled = NO;
}
```

And when you want them enabled just loop again and set `enabled` to `YES`

Answer (score 0):

Keep a Tag to your helpView(imageview) and add the following code

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if (view.tag != yourViewTag) {
            view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
    }
```

And after removing the help screen use the following code

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
            view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution..When help imageview is appearing

```
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) 
    {
        if (view isKindOfClass:[UIButton Class]) 
        {
            view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
       else
        {
            view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    } 

////After dismissing the help screen you can

    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) 
    {
        if (view isKindOfClass:[UIButton Class]) 
        {
            view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
```

////(OR) Simply do as below

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that disables user interaction for all views that are under your helpBackground:

```
- (void)disableUserInteractionForViewsUnderView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect area = view.frame;
    for (UIView *underView in [self.view subviews]) {
        if(CGRectContainsRect(area, underView.frame))
            underView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

and after that you call it where you need it:

```
[self disableUserInteractionForViewsUnderView:self.helpBackground];
```

**EDIT**

I've created a `UIViewController` category gist on github.com. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/alexcristea/0244b50e503e8bf4f25d

You can use it like this:

```
[self enumerateViewsPlacedUnderView:self.helpBackground usingBlock:^(UIView *view) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}];
```